# Problem using PopScope in PageView widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem while using PopScope. I'm using a PageView that contains several pages with PopScope and some processing, but on one of them the processing in PopScope is bound to a widget, so I can't do the processing in the main widget, and the problem is that when scrolling the PageView I have there are two active pages and on exit (this happens to me on a device that has gesture output) PopScope is called on two pages and Navigator.pop is called multiple times, is there a way to handle this so that PopScope is called on the same page , because before that I used WillPopScope and it worked fine

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestView({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestView> createState() => _TestViewState();
}

class _TestViewState extends State<TestView> {
  final PageController pageController = PageController();

  Future<bool> onWillPop() async {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> pages = [
      ///
      TestHeaderView(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
      ),

      ///
      TestProductsView(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
      ),

      ///
      TestCardView(
        onWillPop: onWillPop,
      ),
    ];

    return PageView(
      controller: pageController,
      children: pages,
    );
  }
}

class TestHeaderView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<bool> Function() onWillPop;

  const TestHeaderView({super.key, required this.onWillPop});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        log('Header: didPop: $didPop');

        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }

        final bool res = await onWillPop();

        if (context.mounted && res == true) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Header'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestProductsView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<bool> Function() onWillPop;

  const TestProductsView({super.key, required this.onWillPop});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        log('Products: didPop: $didPop');

        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }

        final bool res = await onWillPop();

        if (context.mounted && res == true) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Products'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestCardView extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<bool> Function() onWillPop;
  const TestCardView({super.key, required this.onWillPop});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
        log('Cart: didPop: $didPop');

        if (didPop) {
          return;
        }

        final bool res = await onWillPop();

        if (context.mounted && res == true) {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Cart'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PopScope logs

[image]

when using the old WillPopScope everything works, but after the update when using PopScope it will work twice